# Why am I getting a silent crash on iOS6?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

I'm at my wit's end trying to figure out a "silent" crash I am getting.  There isn't a specific part of code where it occurs, because I have placed nslogs in several locations and there is no correlation with them and the crash.

I am using **vmtracker** in the instruments allocation tool and my dirty memory varies but crashes as low as 32 MB.  My live bytes in allocations (not **vmtracker**) is stable at around 10-12 MB.

I could understand it if it was some logic error, but this is a silent crash and **xcode** gives no information except **NSZombie_NSException**.

This is from the crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x60000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34da9564 0x34da6000 + 13668
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34da9f84 0x34da6000 + 16260
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34dab1d2 0x34da6000 + 20946
3   CoreFoundation                  0x372ae600 0x371ec000 + 796160
4   CoreFoundation                  0x372ae358 0x371ec000 + 795480
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34daea62 0x34da6000 + 35426
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35a41078 0x35a40000 + 4216
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35a41110 0x35a40000 + 4368
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35a42594 0x35a40000 + 9620
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34dae9cc 0x34da6000 + 35276
10  CoreFoundation                  0x371f4f1c 0x371ec000 + 36636
11  CoreFoundation                  0x371f4d44 0x371ec000 + 36164
12  GraphicsServices                0x34eaa2e6 0x34ea5000 + 21222
13  UIKit                           0x36c6c2fc 0x36c15000 + 357116
14  Pocket Dungeons                 0x0008a2be 0x3a000 + 328382
15  Pocket Dungeons                 0x0003b8bc 0x3a000 + 6332
```

Is 32 MB a lot of dirty memory for iPod Touch 4g, iOS 6?

Comment: @Fire: I'm not sure what you mean by breakpoints.  I can't really step through the code line by line and observe the memory changes because there is far too much iterations.

Comment: Look for Crash log. You will have more information about the crash in it.

Comment: There are things called global breakpoints, which stop the program when an exception is raised. On Xcode, go to the breakpoint editor (⌘6) and click the + button on the bottom; add a global breakpoint.

Comment: @0x8badf00d: I have added some crash log information.

Comment: @NaseivaKhan SIGSEGV refers to an error with memory, bad reference for example. Try the global breakpoint option.

Comment: Looks promising.  Will continue trying in morning and post back here.  Thank you.

Comment: There may be multiple problems.  I now have corrected some errors related to bad accessing but I have noticed there are crashes where there is no crash log recorded.  Those are the actual crashes that are perplexing me so I think I may be back at square one.  The global breakpoints are not working with these (I will edit the post to indicate this).